# how does influxdb achieve time alignment?

Tags: join, time-series, influxdb

Use influxdb to implement queries similar to the following:

```
select a.x, b.y from A a, B b where a.timestamp = b.timestamp;
```

You must know that the time column unit of the two tables A and B is milliseconds. Most of the time, their values may be similar, but it is difficult to be completely equal. In this case, how to filter out the data. I also checked some information, and everyone mentioned something called time alignment. If this is the case, how does influxdb achieve time alignment?
Thank you.

I haven't seen a clear answer on other sites.